# PHP Email content and CSRF protection

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, xss, csrf

I have an app in Codeigniter - PHP that which shows email content from email server. I am showing the email inside an `iframe`. it works perfect.

Currently i dont have a CSRF protection enabled by default for some reasons. But when it comes to email i am concerned about security because emails are coming from outside of the system.

Is there any standard that i need to follow to show emails on web page ? also is there any kind of security issues related with this ?

Also please note that i did many search regarding this, but i couldnt find anything informative articles regarding the problem.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: I have somewhat the same problem you and had the idea for an iframe as well, but haven't found any definitive sources yet, would like to see some as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue about it. I mean, XSS concerns to give security to form submitions.

If your question is related only to show contents... Theres nothing to worry about.

For example, xss is implemented directly in codeigniter forms. It filters all the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

CSRF is mainly for when a form is submit to make sure that its not submitted from outside. As you are not taking any input the CSRF is not a problem.

But when you are displaying email content you might consider doing XSS clean. Where XSS clean remove anything unwanted as you are reading the email and displaying straight to your site. For example an email content is a script and that can send cookie information to someone else. But if you clean your content it will remove the script.

Answer (score 0):

You must 1st learn that what actually CSRF does and how a victim can be attacked by this method?
CSRF is 1 click attack. The attacker forces a user to change the sensitive information of victim like password or email without even letting him know. This attack always require victim's interaction unlike remote exploits. You can open URL in iframe but that does not mean that URL is not protected by CSRF.
If user's input is going to database and there is no CSRF protection then you must do something for it. Otherwise you don't need to be tensed.